# How to control when TextView sends String to new line?

Tags: java, android, string, textview

When a word in a `String` from a `TextView` is too large to fit on the same line as the prior words it skips to the next line. This proves to be very useful. However, this puts me in a dilemma. My `String`, for my particular reasons, needs to have a space in between each letter of a word and two spaces in between words. Because of this the `TextView` will split words having one piece on one line and the other piece on the next. So, I'm thinking I may have to create a custom `View` that extends `TextView` and override the way it skips to the next line. But taking a look at the [class documents for textview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) I can't find a way I would do this. So, any help, advice or suggestions will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: why won't you try to just manually cause a linebreak where needed by "\n"? Assumed you do not have dynamic text content..

Comment: The text is all dynamic. Maybe I could find out the pixel size of an individual character and knowing how many characters there are, where each word starts, and the size of the screen I could build a new String to set in the textview with appropriate line breaks. But that seems a little much.

Comment: Take a look on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18473577/1646326 it is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `TextView` with a few modifications.

The basic strategy will be to override the `onDraw()` method and custom paint your text. You will also have to override `onMeasure()`.

Within `onDraw()` you will pre-process the custom *words* in your string and insert newline characters (`\n`) as necessary.

Loop through the *words* in your text and compare [measureText(String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#measureText%28java.lang.String%29) with the current width of your `TextView` to determine where to insert the newlines. Don't forget to take into account "padding".

**Example**:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onMeasure(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), getSuggestedMinimumHeight());
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // preprocess your text
    canvas.drawText(...);
}
```