# Android: avoid breaking line in TextView String parts

Tags: android, string, textview, newline

I would like to avoid breaking lines in specifical parts of the String.

Let's say we have this String:

```
Speed (m/s)
```

The ideal would be either not jumping at all and having the full String in one line, or, if the jump is needed, in this way:

```
Speed
(m/s)
```

What I want to avoid are thing like this:

```
Speed (m/
s)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134457/how-to-prevent-edittext-from-breaking-a-line-after-punctuation

Answer (score 11):

Try to use [non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) between the Speed and "(m/s)".
The [Unicode no-break space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/A0/index.htm) character (`\u00A0`) should work for TextView.

Comment: The problem here is that there is no space in "(m/s)", but Android is splitting it...

Comment: Since the "(m/s)" is not a word, android cannot wrap it automatically. This problem looks trickier than the space and word wrap issues.. Here is a question which is similar to yours, maybe you can refer the answer that is accepted. They override the `TextView`with a few modifications. [Similar Question's Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981941/how-to-control-when-textview-sends-string-to-new-line?rq=1)

Comment: And note that for some languages like Korean, Chinese, etc, there are no spaces in between. So this this only works for languages that use spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (just an idea, not tested):

1. Calculate the width of the `TextView` with [`View.getMeasuredWidth()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getMeasuredWidth%28%29).
2. Calculate the width of the `String` with [`Paint.measureText()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#measureText%28java.lang.String%29).
3. Compare the widths and add "\n" between "Speed" and "(m/s)" if required.

Comment: I was looking more for a general case... I could get difficult if having several lines and rules at the same time...